# Get By Locator from IWebElement

Tags: c#, selenium

Is there any way to pull the By Locator out of the IWebElement that is currently being used?

Comment: No, there is no property by which the By param used in FindElement for your element object is retained. This is really an interesting question, though, and I'd be curious as to your use case.

Comment: I have a small hope Jim Evans will surprise us!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a built in way to do this, but this can be achieved using the `EventFiringWebDriver` class which has an event member `OnFindElementCompleted`. That event has a parameter of type `FindElementEventArgs` which exposes a `FindMethod` member of type `By` giving you exactly what you need - the `By` parameter you used when calling `FindElement`.

When subscribing to the `OnFindElementCompleted` you can capture the `FindElementEventArgs.FindMethod` value and store it in a static dictionary.

Strangely the `FindElementEventArgs` type has no member to represent the element that was found, so to get the associated element you will have to do a bit of a hack involving using the `Element` member of `FindElementEventArgs`to perform an identical search. You'll probably run into some issue with circular events which you might be able to circumvent by casting `FindElementEventArgs.Driver` to `EventFiringWebDriver` and searching on the `ParentDriver` property.

Sorry I couldn't give you a fuller solution, I'm in bed and doing this on mobile!